# SQL Syntax error (only when run as scheduled job)

Tags: sql-server, scheduled-tasks, ssms

I have just created a scheduled job to run daily, but when the job runs via the scheduler I get the error "Incorrect syntax near 'Item'.  [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 102)".

This only happens when the job is run via the scheduler, and works fine when run directly.

```
DELETE FROM [NAVQueriesDB].[dbo].[New Items on Order] GO
  SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
  GO
 INSERT [NAVQueriesDB].[dbo].[New Items on Order] (
   [Updated Date], 
   [Location Code],
   [Order No_],
   [Item No_],
   [Item Description],
   [Variant Code],
   [Description 2],
   [Outstanding Qty_], 
   [Order Date],
   [Vendor_No],
   [Vendor_Name])

  SELECT  
    GETDATE() AS "Updated Date", 
    [Purch Line].[Location Code],
    [Purch Line].[Document No_],
    [Item].[No_],
    [Item].[Description],
    ISNULL([Purch Line].[Variant Code],'-') AS "Variant Code",
    ISNULL([Variant].[Description 2],'-') AS "Description 2", 
    CAST(SUM([Purch Line].[Outstanding Quantity]) as decimal(18,0)) AS "Outstanding Qty.",
    [Purch Line].[Order Date],
    [Purch Line].[Buy-from Vendor No_],
    [Vendor].[Name]
 FROM [Wings$Item] AS "Item"
  LEFT JOIN [Wings$Purchase Line] AS "Purch Line"
  ON [Item].[No_] = [Purch Line].[No_]

  LEFT JOIN [Wings$Item Variant] AS "Variant"
  ON [Item].[No_] = [Variant].[Item No_] AND [Purch Line].[Variant Code] = [Variant].[Code]

  LEFT JOIN [Wings$Vendor] AS "Vendor"
  ON [Purch Line].[Buy-from Vendor No_] = [Vendor].[No_]

  LEFT JOIN [Wings$Item Ledger Entry] AS "Item Ledger"
  ON [Item].[No_] = [Item Ledger].[Item No_]

  WHERE
    [Item].[No_] > '5618%'
    AND [Item].[No_] <> 'Z999999'
    AND [Item Ledger].[Item No_] IS NULL
 GROUP BY
  [Purch Line].[Location Code],
  [Purch Line].[Document No_], 
  [Item].[No_], 
  [Item].[Description],
  [Purch Line].[Variant Code], 
  [Variant].[Description 2],
  [Purch Line].[Outstanding Quantity], 
  [Purch Line].[Order Date],
  [Purch Line].[Buy-from Vendor No_], 
  [Vendor].[Name]
ORDER BY
  [Location Code],
  [Item].[No_],
  [Item].[Description],
  [Purch Line].[Variant Code]
```

Comment: Could it have something to do with changing the name of the table [Wings$Item] AS "Item" and then referring to it as "Item" the rest of the time in the join statements? Have you try changing your joins to using Wings$Item instead of "Item"?

Comment: Do you need to `Use [NavQueriesDB]` before the `select`?  The opening bits use fully-qualified table names but the select doesn't.

Comment: @Hellion I need to set that because I am running this query in one database to populate data in another SQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad idea (IMO) to use double quotes for your identifiers. The standard is `[]` if it has to be quoted (which is also why I avoid spaces in my names so that I don't have to quote them).

SQL Agent defaults to `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` being set to `OFF`. If you change the double quotes to brackets then this should work. Alternatively (but not recommended), you could include the first line of your script to be `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON`.

For example, `GETDATE() AS "Updated Date"`... `GETDATE() AS [Updated Date]` is better. `GETDATE() AS updated_date` is best.

Comment: Thanks @Tom.  Appreciate the response!  Setting the quoted identifier to on worked.  Will take your advice going forward on using best practice with brackets!